# Office365 Management API - Search for content

Tags: office365, office365-apps, office365api, office365-restapi

Is there any way to **search content** in files in the **Office365 Management API**?

Like the way Dropbox for Business does it
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-search

> **mode** *SearchMode* The search mode (filename, **filename_and_content**, or deleted_filename). Note that **searching file content is only available for Dropbox Business accounts**. The default for this union is filename.

Or Box for Enterprises does it
https://box-content.readme.io/reference#searching-for-content

> **query** The string to search for; can be matched against item names, descriptions, text content of a file, and other fields of the different item types.
>
> **scope** Can be user_content for a search limited to only the current user or enterprise_content for the entire enterprise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use graph.microsoft.com to access user's files. You can specify localtion, folder, file metadata in the resource item type as well for files.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children

Complete resource type filters for files in OneDrive:

http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem

There is also a search item endpoint:
http://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_search

Hope this helps.

Comment: great. let us know how it goes.